# JUnit comparison Failure string change

Tags: java, junit

for my JUNIT test case:

```
Map<String, Object> input = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    String operator = "in";
    String argument = "foo";
    String field = "AvailabilityStatus";
    Map<String, Object> innerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    List<String> innerInnerList = new ArrayList<String>();
    innerInnerList.add(argument);
    innerMap.put(operator, innerInnerList);
    input.put(field, innerMap);

    output = HypervisorResourceUtil.convertToCriteria(input);
    System.out.println("Size of output is :" + output.size());
    for (Criterion c : output) {
        StringBuilder expectedOutputTmp = new StringBuilder().append(field).append(operator).append(argument);
        assertEquals(c.toString(), expectedOutputTmp.toString());
```

and the error:

> HypervisorResourceUtil INFO : Values: [foo]
> Size of output is :1
>
> org.junit.ComparisonFailure:
> Expected :AvailabilityStatus in (foo)
> Actual   :AvailabilityStatusinfoo

I tried adding spaces: Availability(space), in(space) and foo. still, no change. Any help please? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what does the error mean? and why is there a [] in the input? is the input modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `assertEquals` method backwards. The first argument should be the expected value and the second argument should be your actual result. It should be:

```
assertEquals(expectedOutputTmp.toString(), c.toString());
```

Based on the (backwards) error message, if you want your test to pass then your expected string needs to contain `"AvailabilityStatus in (foo)"`. E.g.

```
String expectedOutput = String.format("%s %s (%s)", field, operator, argument);
assertEquals(expectedOutput, c.toString());
```

Note: you can construct this `expectedOutput` string outside your for loop, since it doesn't need to change within it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with JUnit's `assertEquals`, the `expected` value is passed in first, then the `actual` value (cd. the [API](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html)). And as your temporary `StringBuilder` contains no spaces, the test will continue to fail. The good news is that your actual `String` seems to be what you want it to be :).

Try  `StringBuilder expectedOutputTmp = new StringBuilder().append(field).append(" ").append(operator).append(" ").append(argument)`, and play around with it (perhaps `System.out.println()`ing the `StringBuilder.toString()` output) until it works.